# installing velocyto (clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp' error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1)

Tags: python, gcc, clang

I tried to install a python package called 'velocyto', however, I get the error:
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I tried different ways ppl suggested such as,

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++" ..
brew install cmake gcc
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-6 CMakeLists.txt
make
```

Which didn't help for the installation of velocyto.

Here's the entire error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 

/Users/Yi/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 

'"'"'/private/var/folders/4f/nng016r569gdc7bc0tbt4_900000gn/T/pip-install-xo7ufdqy/velocyto/setup.py'"'"'; 

__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4f/nng016r569gdc7bc0tbt4_900000gn/T/pip-install-xo7ufdqy/velocyto/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 

'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 

/private/var/folders/4f/nng016r569gdc7bc0tbt4_900000gn/T/pip-record-oyv7kr4s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/Yi/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/velocyto Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks a lot for your help! I really want to install this package and keep analyzing the data.

Best,
Yi